# How to plot a graph from a matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, graph

I have a matrix which is 100 rows and 2 columns, I want to plot a graph on MATLAB with 1st column being x values, and 2nd column as y values. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try `plot(a(:,1),a(:,2));` where `a` is your matrix.